# Use GroupBy to eliminate repetitive objects from List<T>

Tags: c#, list, group-by

How can I use `GroupBy` to get a distinct list of points. I want to eliminate the repetitive points.

```
List<_3DPoint> list_of_points = new List<_3DPoint> { ... };

public class _3DPoint
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `groupby`?  Its function is not to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: You can GroupBy by multiple keys list_of_points.GroupBy(x => new { x.X, x.Y, x.Z });, but this will not eliminate the same points. Distinct is the proper way

Comment: @Vahid because it does work another way, why do you think it should work? ;) Grouping two same items will give you a group of two items, simply because you've grouped two items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `GroupBy`, consider implementing `IEquatable<ThreeDPoint>` and using `Enumerable.Distinct`.

```
public class ThreeDPoint : IEquatable<ThreeDPoint>
{
    public bool Equals(ThreeDPoint other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return X.Equals(other.X) && Y.Equals(other.Y) && Z.Equals(other.Z);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((ThreeDPoint) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = X.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ Y.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ Z.GetHashCode();
            return hashCode;
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(ThreeDPoint left, ThreeDPoint right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(ThreeDPoint left, ThreeDPoint right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }

    public ThreeDPoint(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public double X { get; private set; }
    public double Y { get; private set; }
    public double Z { get; private set; }
}
```

And now do:

```
var points = new List<ThreeDPoint> { // Add elements };
points.Distinct();
```

**Edit:**

If you're still convinced you want the `GroupBy` (I would definitely recommend using the `IEquatable<T>` approach), you can do it like this:

```
var list = new List<ThreeDPoint> 
{ 
    new ThreeDPoint(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), 
    new ThreeDPoint(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), 
    new ThreeDPoint(2.0, 2.0, 2.0), 
    new ThreeDPoint(2.0, 2.0, 2.0) 
};

var distinctResult = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.X, x.Y, x.Z })
                         .Select(x => x.First());
```

Comment: Thanks Yuval. The distinct is okay. But I was wondering how can this be done using `GroupBy`.

Comment: Thanks Yuval, I don't understand why using GroupBy would leave me with duplicate objects sometimes?

Comment: `GroupBy` will only create a grouping based on the element you pass it. Then, once grouped, you have to pick our only the first element out of the group, because that's what you actually want to get, a single instance.

Comment: So if I use the `First` I will have no problem right?

Comment: `Enumerable.First` picks the first element. If there are no elements, it throws an `InvalidOperationException` of the sequence is empty. But, `GroupBy` will ensure that there is at least one element in the group, so you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much Yuval for a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

List<_3DPoint> list_of_points = new List<_3DPoint> { ... };

var noDuplicates = list_of_points.Distinct().ToList();

You might want to Override Equals and GetHashCode for not only removing duplicate references in the list but also Equal Data.

Comment: Thanks John. Can you explain what you mean by equal data?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a duplicate is for you if there a 2 different instances of the _3DPoint class with equal X,Y and Z values. Yuval covered that in his answer by overriding Equals!